# Diagrama de casos de uso - include e extend

Tags: uml, casos-de-uso

Já foram feitas perguntas parecidas com a que vou fazer, mas não consigo entender e aplicar para o meu cenário.

Tenho os seguintes cadastros: 
 - Cadastro de categoria de equipamento 
 - Cadastro de equipamento

Para se cadastrar um equipamento, é necessário selecionar uma categoria de equipamento.

Como ficaria meu diagrama de caso de uso? Cadastrar equipamento inclui cadastrar categoria ou cadastrar categoria estende cadastrar equipamento?

[image: exemplos]

Comment: O que se cadastra primeiro, a categoria ou o equipamento? Por exemplo, primeiro se cria uma categoria vazia, depois se cria o equipamento dessa categoria? É isso?

Comment: Na verdade o `cadastrar equipamento` deveria chamar `selecionar categoria` e não `cadastrar`, ou estou enganado?

Comment: Primeiro a categoria. Ao entrar no cadastro de equipamento, tem um combobox com as categorias existentes, porém se não existir a que usuário quer, tem um botão ao lado que abre o cadastro de categoria, quando a tela fechar, atualiza a combobox.

Comment: Então categoria nunca pode chamar o `cadastrar equipamento`. Agora tem que ver se o equipamento vai incluir ou estender o categoria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de mais nada precisamos entender as diferenças dos dois relacionamentos dos casos de uso.

## Relacionamento de inclusão

É quando um caso de uso base faz uso do caso de uso estendido. O caso de uso base, ao encontrar o ponto em que o relacionamento de inclusão está definido, então nesse momento a execução da instância do caso de uso é transferida para o caso de uso incluída, e uma instância do mesmo é criada. Quando a execução da instância do caso de uso incluída termina, então o controle retorna para o caso de uso base no mesmo ponto anterior.

O relacionamento de inclusão não é condicional.

[image: inclusao]

## Relacionamento de extensão

Já o relacionamento de extensão é condicional, o que significa que sua execução depende do que tiver acontecido durante a execução do caso de uso base. O caso de uso base não controla as condições da execução da extensão. Essas condições são descritas no relacionamento de extensão.

[image: extensao]

Fonte: [Estruturar os casos de uso - Aluízo Saiter](http://puces2010.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Introdu%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20a%20Engenharia%20de%20Software/Material/Handout%20das%20Aulas%20em%20PDF/Capitulo%2011%20-%20Estruturar%20os%20Caso%20de%20Uso.pdf)

---

## Solução

Como você disse que a categoria pode ser criada mesmo sem um equipamento para ela, não haverá a menor chance do caso de uso "Cadastrar categoria" incluir ou estender o "Cadastrar equipamento". O que vai vincular os dois casos de uso é quando o usuário criar um equipamento para uma categoria que não existe.

Portanto, por haver uma condição, o correto é que o caso de uso "Cadastrar equipamento" estenda "Cadastrar categoria".

Comment: obrigado. no caso dos diagramas que desenhei, o segundo está correto ou preciso inverter a flecha?

Comment: Precisa inverter.